# AVAudioRecorder background modes and phone call

Tags: objective-c

My app Used Required background modes "App plays audio"
I can record on background mode. but if phone call?
I used the delegate

```
-(void)loadView
{    
  NSError *error=nil;
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];

  if (error) {//Do something error}

  error = nil;

  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&error];
  if (error) {//Do something error}
}

-(void)audioRecorderBeginInterruption

{

   [AVAudioRecorder  pause];

}

-(void)audioRecorderEndInterruption

{

   [AVAudioRecorder  record];

}
```

These two methods are executed normally
But `AVAudioRecorder` is not Run.

I want keep recording when the phone call end.

Comment: I try to Remote Control & background modes together can keep run when the audioRecorderEndInterruption .
But my AVAudioRecorder Force Quit.
I need pause . Not stop. I want continue recording.
Who has better solution??

Answer (score 1):

try this delegate method,

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application 
{

//post your Notification
}
```

it should be call back at your working class which include your method,

```
-(void)audioRecorderEndInterruption

{
// add Notification
   [AVAudioRecorder  record];

}
```